# Prolog (Sicstus) - setof and findall combination issues

Tags: prolog, prolog-setof

Given a set of routes a given station has, such us :

```
route(TubeLine, ListOfStations).

route(green, [a,b,c,d,e,f]).
route(blue, [g,b,c,h,i,j]).
...
```

I am required to find names of lines that have a specific station in common. The result must be ordered, with non-repeated stations and must return an empty list, if there were no results. So, querying

```
| ?- lines(i, Ls).
```

Should give:

```
Ls = [blue,red,silver] ? ;
no
```

I tried doing the following:

```
lines(X, L) :- setof(L1, findall(W, (route(W, Stations),member(X, Stations)),L1), L).
```

However,  it gives the following as an answer:

```
Is = [[blue,silver,red]];
no
```

So unordered with double braces. I tried using just findall, but the result is not ordered. I know I could then write sort function and pass that through, however I was wondering if it is possible to use just findall and setof in this instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's easier than your attempt, but you need to grasp the peculiar setof' behaviour wrt free variables, and account for the eventuality that an unknown station was required (setof/3 fails if there are no solutions).

```
 lines(X, Ls) :-
   setof(L, Stations^(route(L, Stations), member(X, Stations)), Ls)
   -> true ; Ls = [].
```

An easier alternative, as you said, use findall/3 exactly as you're doing (without setof!), and sort the output.

Comment: I see! Thank you for your answer! Do you know any resources where I could practice such behaviour?

Comment: the whole [chapter 11](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlch11) of 'learn Prolog now' is worth to read, and specifically the [setof/3 section](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse49)