# Prolog (Sicstus) - nonmember and setof issues

Tags: prolog, prolog-setof

Given following facts:

```
route(TubeLine, ListOfStations).

route(green, [a,b,c,d,e,f]).
route(blue, [g,b,c,h,i,j]).
...
```

I am required to find all the pairs of tube Lines that do not have any stations in common, producing the following:

```
| ?- disjointed_lines(Ls).
Ls = [(yellow,blue),(yellow,green),(yellow,red),(yellow,silver)] ? ;
no
```

I came up with the below answer, however it does not only give me incorrect answer, but it also does not apply my X^ condition - i.e. it still prints results per member of Stations lists separately:

```
disjointed_lines(Ls) :- 
                        route(W, Stations1),
                        route(Z, Stations2),
                        setof(
                        (W,Z),X^
                        (member(X, Stations1),nonmember(X, Stations2)),
                         Ls).
```

This is the output that the definition produces:

```
| ?- disjointed_lines(L).
L = [(green,green)] ? ;
L = [(green,blue)] ? ;
L = [(green,silver)] ? ;
...
```

I believe that my logic relating to membership is incorrect, however I cannot figure out what is wrong. Can anyone see where am I failing?

I also read Learn Prolog Now chapter 11 on results gathering as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509065/prolog-sicstus-setof-and-findall-combination-issues), however it seems that I am still unable to use the ^ operator correctly. Any help would be appreciated!

---

***UPDATE:***

As suggested by user CapelliC, I changed the code into the following:

```
disjointed_lines(Ls) :- 
                        setof(
                        (W,Z),(Stations1, Stations2)^
                        ((route(W, Stations1),
                        route(Z, Stations2),notMembers(Stations1,Stations2))),
                         Ls).

notMembers([],_).
notMembers([H|T],L):- notMembers(T,L), nonmember(H,L).
```

The following, however, gives me duplicates of (X,Y) and (Y,X), but the next step will be to remove those in a separate rule. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should put route/2 calls inside setof' goal, and express disjointness more clearly, so you can test it separately. About the `^` operator, it requests a variable to be *universally quantified* in goal scope. Maybe a concise explanation like that found at [bagof/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=bagof/3) manual page will help...

```
disjointed_lines(Ls) :- 
  setof((W,Z), Stations1^Stations2^(
    route(W, Stations1),
    route(Z, Stations2),
    disjoint(Stations1, Stations2)
  ), Ls).

disjoint(Stations1, Stations2) :-
  ... % could be easy as intersection(Stations1, Stations2, [])
      % or something more efficient: early fail at first shared 'station'
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I added the following definition to fix the problem following your suggestion:  notMembers([],_).
notMembers([H|T],L):- notMembers(T,L), nonmember(H,L).  The full solution gives me duplicates of [(X,Y),(Y,X)] so removing those duplicates would be the last step for me :)

Comment: To remove duplicates, you can use `W @< Z` as an additional goal in your `setof` call.

Answer (score 1):

`setof/3` is easier to use if you create an auxiliary predicate that expresses the relationship you are interested in:

```
disjoint_routes(W, Z) :-
    route(W, Stations1),
    route(Z, Stations2),
    disjoint(Stations1, Stations2).
```

With this, the definition of `disjointed_lines/1` becomes shorter and simpler *and no longer needs any `^` operators*:

```
disjointed_lines(Ls) :-
    setof((W, Z), disjoint_routes(W, Z), Ls).
```

The variables you don't want in the result of `setof/3` are automatically hidden inside the auxiliary predicate definition.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is a great tip! I will definitely use it if I had any more troubles with ^ :)